# Why alarm manager is stoped by another application

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, background-service

I implement alarm manager in my android application.

```
private void setAlarmManager() {
    String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(alarm);
    Intent intent = new Intent( "REFRESH_LOCATION" );
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent,0);
    int type = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
    long interval = 2*60*1000;
    long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    am.setRepeating(type, 0, interval, pi);
}
```

Some applications (installed by default) stop my application and alarm manager and we have to manage settings of those applications to disable stopping alarm manager in my application.

Is there any solution to control another applications that don't stop my alarm manager? or Is there any solution to detect those applications?

Comment: have you checked this happens in  every API device?

Comment: What do you mean by other application?Specify name

Comment: @jiteshmohite application that installed by default like power saver

Comment: @VishalThakkar no. but and I want to work my alarm manager in api devices >= 16

Comment: Then how you are managing "manage settings of those applications to disable stopping alarm manager in my application."?

Comment: @jiteshmohite open those application and change settings of my application on those.

Comment: @jiteshmohite ... and in asus tablet has an app power manager that stop alar manager